# How to convert a .reduce function of Javascript to Python?

Tags: javascript, python

I am reading a javascript source and I need to convert it to Python.

Here is the code, since I am just a beginner, I dont get `.reduce()` function at all

```js
function bin2dec(num){
    return num.split('').reverse().reduce(function(x, y, i){
        return (y === '1') ? x + Math.pow(2, i) : x;
    }, 0);
}
```

Here is what I have tried so far

```py
def bin2dec(num):
    listNum = list(num)
    listNum = map(int, listNum)
    x = listNum[-1]
    listNum.reverse()
    for i in range (len(listNum)):
        if listNum[i] == 1:
            x = x + 2**listNum[i]
        else:
            x = x
    return x
```

But it is not correct.

Comment: It’s silly in JavaScript too, because there’s `let bin2dec = num => parseInt(num, 2);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Normal Equivalence**

- Javascript `parseInt(x, 2)`
- Python `int(x, 2)`

**Using Same Method as Posted Code**

```
from functools import reduce
import math

def bin2dec(s):
    return reduce(lambda x, y_i: x + int(math.pow(2, y_i[0])) if y_i[1] == '1' else x, 
                  enumerate(reversed(s)), 
                  0)
```

*Test*

```
print(bin2dec('110'))  # outut: 6
```

*Explanation*

- `reversed(s)` to replace Javascript `num.split('').reverse()`
- Python's `reduce` function from [functools](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html) has signature `reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])`

  - Use Python lambda function in place of Javascript's `function(x, y, i){...` (1st argument)
  - Javascript reduce provide current value and current index `y, i`
  - Python only provides current value, so we use enumerate(..) on values array to convert to current index, current value pairs (2nd argument)
  - `y_i` are value tuples, with y_i[0] = index and y_i[1] the value
  - use 0 as initializer (last argument in reduce)
- int to convert the value of math.pow from float to integer
- Python `if else` expression in place of Javascript's `?` ternary operator

**Simpler Python Code than Using Reduce**

```
def bin2dec(s):
    return sum((0, 2**i)[y == '1'] for i, y in enumerate(s[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the built-in `int` function:

```py
int("010010", 2)

>>> 18
```

---

That said I found a pretty interesting alternative approach using [js2py](https://pypi.org/project/Js2Py/).
You can feed it the whole js function as a string, allowing you to effectively use js inside python:

```py
import js2py

bin2dec = js2py.eval_js("""
function bin2dec(num){
    return num.split('').reverse().reduce(function(x, y, i){
        return (y === '1') ? x + Math.pow(2, i) : x;
    }, 0);
}
""")

bin2dec("010010")

>>> 18
```

Install with `pip install js2py`

---

You made a lot of mistakes with your attempt, the `map` function returns an `iterator`, not a `list`. Generally, just avoid `map` and `filter` and just use a list comprehension instead.

You also raised 2 to the power of the value (1 or 0) when it should have been the index.

Here's a working version of your example:

```py
def bin2dec(num):
    listNum = [int(n) for n in num]
    total = 0
    listNum.reverse()
    for i, n in enumerate(listNum):
        if n == 1:
            total += 2 ** i
    return total
```